# ERROR: Cannot define class using reflection

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, selenium, npm

I'm making App by using this [webpage](https://hackernoon.com/a-guide-to-tdd-a-react-redux-todolist-app-part-1-b8a200bb7091)

I tried to test e2e-tests, however it didn't work.

This program failed to start selenium server. How do I fix this?

npm-v :5.6.0

yarn-v :1.5.1

os -v :10.12.6

Besides, I'm already done with the test that selenium server would work or not. As a result, selenium server also didn't work.

I tried [this way](https://gist.github.com/stoshiya/3dc36187ede3e6eee3e4) to test selenium server

e2e-tests error is below

```
ERROR: Cannot define class using reflection chrome at new RuntimeError

(/Users/hajimenagasaka/my-react-todolist/node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/ErrorHandler.js:144:12) at Request._callback

(/Users/hajimenagasaka/my-react-todolist/node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/RequestHandler.js:316:39) at Request.self.callback

(/Users/hajimenagasaka/my-react-todolist/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22) at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) at Request.emit (events.js:214:7) at Request.

(/Users/hajimenagasaka/my-react-todolist/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10) at emitOne (events.js:116:13) at Request.emit (events.js:211:7) at IncomingMessage.

(/Users/hajimenagasaka/my-react-todolist/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12) at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! my-react-todolist@0.1.0 e2e-tests: wdio

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the my-react-todolist@0.1.0 e2e-tests script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

**selenium test result**

```
Selenium 2.0/webdriver protocol bindings implementation with helper commands in nodejs.

For a complete list of commands, visit http://webdriver.io/docs.html.

======================================================================

[17:03:28]:ERROR Couldn't find a running selenium server instance on [object Object]/Users/hajimenagasaka/node_modules/chainit/index.js:140

throw err;
^

Error: [init()] <= Couldn't connect to selenium server at makeError (/Users/hajimenagasaka/node_modules/webdriverjs/lib/utils/makeError.js:9:17)

at RequestHandler.<anonymous> (/Users/hajimenagasaka/node_modules/webdriverjs/lib/utils/RequestHandler.js:177:25)

at self.callback (/Users/hajimenagasaka/node_modules/request/request.js:122:22) at emitOne (events.js:116:13)

at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)

at ClientRequest.self.clientErrorHandler (/Users/hajimenagasaka/node_modules/request/request.js:231:10)

at emitOne (events.js:116:13)

at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)

at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
```

**package.json**

```
{   "name": "my-react-todolist",   "version": "0.1.0",   "private": true,   "dependencies": {
    "chrome": "^0.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.46.1",
    "jest-cli": "^22.4.3",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "selenium": "^2.20.0",
    "v": "^0.3.0",
    "webdriver.js": "^0.1.0",
    "webdriverjs": "^1.7.5"   },


    "devDependencies": {
        "chai": "^4.1.2",
        "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
        "eslint": "^3.19.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.6.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
        "react-scripts": "1.0.7",
        "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1",
        "selenium-standalone": "^6.5.0",
        "wdio-dot-reporter": "0.0.8",
        "wdio-mocha-framework": "^0.5.13",
        "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "0.0.9",
        "webdriverio": "^4.8.0"   },


    "scripts": {
        "selenium-setup": "selenium-standalone install",
        "selenium-start": "selenium-standalone start",
        "e2e-tests": "wdio",
        "e2e-tests-watch": "wdio wdio.conf.js --watch",
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
          "start":"selenium-standalone start",      "selenium": "selenium-standalone",   } }
```

**e2etests/test.js**

```
    const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('TodoList App', () => {
  it('Should load with the right title', () => {
    browser.url('http://localhost:3000/');
    const actualTitle = browser.getTitle();

    expect(actualTitle).to.eql('Todo List');
  });
});
```

**src/App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';

it('App renders without crashing', () => {
  const component = shallow(<App />);
  expect(component.exists()).toEqual(true);
});
```

Comment: Please provide your webdriver dependency (or the package.json) and also a snippet of your testing code

Comment: I added package.json .I thought the part of selenium test result is gonna be testing snippet. if not, i would appreciate to teach me where can I get 
snippet of my testing code . Thank you

Comment: the snippet I am talking about is the  part of your testing  code, you don't need to add several  dependencies of  the  webdriver. I already wrote a sample code using webdriver  with chai. If interested i can write you a snippet

Comment: Thank you for replying me.  I really really appreciate that you wrote me a snipet.Btw i want to know what's wrong with my program??

Comment: Actually i really do not know because  you didn't provide  any code snippet of your tests, i will write  a sample of  the testing code i used

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue as well. The solution for me was to install a [JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), as WDIO v4 is apparently not compatible with many newer versions of Java. It is an issue with the `wdio-selenium-standalone-service`.

Comment: downgrading to JDK8 as a asolution is also supported by https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/4657

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, please visit this [link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver) for further information.

Make sure  to add  this dependency `npm install selenium-webdriver` and  the adequate `driver` for your favorite  browser (please pay attention to versions).

First, start your test file by declaring  these variables:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
const React = require ('react');
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome    = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

const By = webdriver.By;
const until = webdriver.until;
const options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments('--headless'); // by adding this, chrome will start in headless mode
```

Next, build your driver

```
const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.forBrowser('chrome')
.withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()) 
.setChromeOptions(options)  
.build();
```

Then, you are ready to start hacking, but never  forget that everything is `ASYNC`.

I used this snippet to test login (for example)

```
// ask the browser to open a page
driver.get('http://localhost:3000/')
/**
 * LOGIN PAGE => THEN LOGIN INFO THEN PRESS CONNECT BUTTON
 */
.then(() => driver.findElements(By.xpath('//input')))
.then((inputs) => {
    inputs[0].sendKeys('username');
    inputs[1].sendKeys('password');
})
.then(() => captureScreenshot(driver, `${__dirname}/images/login-${new 

Date().getTime()}.png`))
    .then(() => console.log('screenshot captured'))
    .then(() => driver.findElement(By.xpath('//button')))
    .then((connectButton) => connectButton.click())
    /**
 * WAIT FOR LOGIN TO FINISH
 */
.then(() => driver.wait(function() {
    return driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@mode='indeterminate']/div"))
    .then(function(elements) {
        return elements.length === 0;
    })
}), 10000)
.then(() => {
    console.log('test done!');
    driver.quit();
});
```

To capture a screenshot, you can use this  function:

```
const captureScreenshot = (driver, savedFile) => {
    console.log('i will save screendshot to ' + savedFile);
    return driver.takeScreenshot()
    .then(
        function(image, err) {
            require('fs').writeFile(savedFile, image, { encoding: 'base64', flag: 'wx' }, function(err) {
                if(err) console.log('error occured', err);
                return Promise.resolve();
            });
        }
    );
}
```

Hope this will help you creating your e-2-e tests.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me !! When I read your cade I just came up on this 

is this that I will write below snipett that you want ?? If it is , Im gonna add this to my question for Visibility ///

below is test.js----------
const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('TodoList App', () => {
  it('Should load with the right title', () => {
    browser.url('http://localhost:3000/');
    const actualTitle = browser.getTitle();

    expect(actualTitle).to.eql('Todo List');
  });
});

-------

Comment: Yes please add your code to the question and format it for visibility

Comment: Where do you get the browser var ? actually, the code i posted works perfectly. you  can try it, it s very simple and complete

Comment: ah, which file should I add these code to? src/App.test.js or e2etests/test.js ??

Comment: In the e2etests/test.js, but first remove your dependencies and  run the npm install in  my answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with WebdriverIO v4 and installing Java 8 resolved the problem as recommended above.

I'd just want to recommend if you want to keep several versions of Java like v11 and v8 you should look at this manual which shows how to toggle between different versions of Java.
https://medium.com/@devkosal/switching-java-jdk-versions-on-macos-80bc868e686a