# Host header or origin header is specified and is not localhost for selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to set up a selenium grid using the latest chrome and chromedriver. I get the following error when trying to run a test

```
Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. Host header or origin header is specified and is not localhost.
```

On the node machine, I see the chrome browser open, but then it immediately closes and I get this error:

```
[1557513678.682][SEVERE]: Rejecting request with host: <hub_IP_address>:4444
```

Has anyone had this issue using the selenium grid? I am using:

- selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar and
- Chromedriver 74.0.3729.6 for windows
- My Chrome browser was running v.74.0.3729.108
- JDK 12.0.1.0

Here is my command for starting the hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar -role hub -hubConfig config.json
```

Here is my command to start a node:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\...\Browsers\ChromeDirectory\chromedriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\...\Browsers\IEDirectory\x86\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar -Dwebdriver.edge.driver="C:\...\Browsers\Edge\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" -jar "C:\...\selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar" -role node -hub "http://<hub_IP_address>:4444/grid/register/" -nodeConfig "C:\...\config.json"
```

I tried using a "host" property in the config.jsons. I tried putting the actual IP address and just localhost.  But the hub and the node are obviously different machines, so putting localhost makes it so they can't connect.  But when I dont have localhost, it says it needs to be specified as localhost? I'm so confused!! What is supposed to go in the host property?

I have seen people talk about a loopback property for protractor but I am not using protractor.  I tried putting "loopback":true into both my node and hub config.json files but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

UPDATE: 
I was able to get the grid to run successfully using the 4.0 alpha jar for the hub, and the old 3.8 jars for the nodes. All Still on Java 8.  Kind of interesting.

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Selenium-Grid-4#hub-and-node  I found some information here about how to run the grid using the new selenium 4 jars, but when I run it using these instructions I cannot get the grid and the node to connect to each other.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get the selenium grid working by downgrading to 3.8.1 selenium grid jar and installing JDK 8 instead of 12.  The reason I needed to get java 8 is answered in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706040/error-cannot-define-class-using-reflection).  I used the same chrome driver and start up commands

Answer (score 4):

You can try to add these switches: *--whitelisted-ips --allowed-origins='*'*

Try to run your node with command:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\...\Browsers\ChromeDirectory\chromedriver.exe --whitelisted-ips --allowed-origins='*'" -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\...\Browsers\IEDirectory\x86\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar -Dwebdriver.edge.driver="C:\...\Browsers\Edge\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" -jar "C:\...\selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar" -role node -hub "http://<hub_IP_address>:4444/grid/register/" -nodeConfig "C:\...\config.json"
```